# Pygame drawing doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, drawing, pygame, draw

I have a problem with drawing a simple rectangle on the screen. I've no clue why it fails to draw, I've tried several things: drawing it on the background surface, changing the order of the function calls etc. but it just doesn't seem to draw anything. As you can see, the enemy() method is supposed to draw a red rectangle, instead it draws nothing. The game runs fine otherwise. I'm sure its something simple I've overlooked.. frustrating!

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.time import *
from pygame.font import *
from pygame.draw import *
import sys
pygame.font.init()
pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700,300))
pygame.display.set_caption('something')

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

velX = 0
velY = 0
playerx = 20
player_filename = 'player.png'
player = pygame.image.load(player_filename)
playery = 150
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def draw():         
    global velX
    global velY
    global playerx
    global playery

    red = pygame.Color(255,0,0)
    black = pygame.Color(0,0,0)

    level = "1"
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    playerx = playerx + velX
    playery = playery + velY
    screen.blit(player, (playerx,playery))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    text = font.render(level, 1, black)
    screen.blit(text, (670,10))
    pygame.display.flip()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def enemySquares():
    enemySurf = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    red = pygame.Color(255,0,0)
    enemy = pygame.Rect(200,50,20,20)
    pygame.draw.rect(enemySurf, red, enemy, 0)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def collisionWithBorder():
    if playerx > 680 or playerx < 0:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if playery > 280 or playery < 0:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def playerFunc():
    keys_down = pygame.key.get_pressed()    
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,50)
    time = 50/1000
    global velX
    global velY
    direction = -1

    if keys_down[K_d]:
        direction = 0
    if keys_down[K_a]:
        direction = 3
    if keys_down[K_w]:
        direction = 1
    if keys_down[K_s]:
        direction = 2

    if direction == 0:
        velX = 50*time
        velY = 0
    if direction == 1:
        velY = -50*time
        velX = 0
    if direction == 2:
        velY = 50*time
        velX = 0
    if direction == 3:
        velX = -50*time
        velY = 0

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

def main(): 
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():   
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        clock.tick(50)        
        collisionWithBorder()
        draw()
        playerFunc()
        enemySquares()

#--------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def enemySquares():
    enemySurf = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    red = pygame.Color(255,0,0)
    enemy = pygame.Rect(200,50,20,20)
    pygame.draw.rect(enemySurf, red, enemy, 0)
```

The function above does draw a red rectangle - on a new surace it creates, not on
the "screen" surface.

Just drop your `enemySurf = ...` line there and change `pygame.draw.rect(enemySurf, red, enemy, 0)`
to 
`pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, enemy, 0)` to have the rectangle apear on the next call to `pygame.display.flip()`

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. Did'nt seem to have any effect :(

Comment: It didn't work because in your main loop, you're calling `draw()`, and then after that you're calling `enemySquares()`.  Your `draw()` function is drawing the background and updating the screen, so you're drawing the enemy rect after you draw the background and flip the screen, then you draw over that rect again on the next loop of `draw()`.  So essentially, the rect is being drawn over on each frame before you update the screen again.  If you put the call to `enemySquares()` inside of the `draw()` function, and before the call to flip the screen, it should work.

Comment: did get it to work with what jsbueno said in the end, my bad for misunderstanding what he said first